# Script call at end of HTML causing page to render differently in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, resize

I ran into an issue today while working on a new form and it had me stuck and confused as to what was going on for almost an hour. Eventually the last thing I tried was replacing a useless script call I had at the very bottom of my HTML code.

This is what I had before:

```
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I added:

```
</form>
<script src="script_printpage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the script file is only this:

```
function printPage() {
    window.print();
}
```

So now that you know what I had and what I changed, let me explain what was going on.

I had a simple page (that I can't access from home, so I can't post it) that had a container around, some basic formatting, you name it. It wasn't really fancy or anything and I keep a tight ship on all my spacing and elements. All my other forms I have done also have this script at the bottom so that meant I never saw this issue until now.

If I add any input element like an input type text, when I refresh the page with the script line not present, the text control will actually "grow" for a split second until it reaches normal size and normal appearance. I print-screened it at work and saw what it looked like the very moment it loaded and it was like there was no padding or anything and there was only a thick black border.

This behavior would repeat pretty much every single time I refreshed the page. I could sit there and constantly refresh and it would always do it. It's hard to explain but basically the input control starts smaller and "grows" up to the normal expected size in a fraction of a second if the script line at the bottom is missing.

If I re-add this script line at the bottom, it never happens. The page loads and the text control is already at normal size and no amount of refreshing changes its appearance.

What could be causing elements to resize on page load like this? And why on Earth does a script that's doing nothing affect this? I wish I could give you all the code I have but I can't access it from home.

I tried this code through Edge and it never happened with or without the script call and in my testing it doesn't happen in Firefox either. The computer I work on was on the latest version of Chrome, so I know it happens now on the current version, whatever it is.

Any help with this would be great. For now I can keep this useless script at the bottom just so I am not driven insane.

Comment: Some new-arizen Chrome bug? Hard to tell

Comment: It's going to be really hard to answer this without seeing the HTML and reproducing it. Couldn't you wait until you got to work to post the question?

Comment: sounds like the rendering pauses while the tag is fetched/parses, which might drop the un-closed tags into some kind of quirks layout that gets fixed once the legit closing tags are parsed after the script.